# How to parse slice from an other function

Tags: go

I have the following Go snippet. I have a slice

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    y := []int{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8}
    return y
}

func toParseY(int y) {
    for i, v := range y {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
    }
}
```

I know that I have to pass the slice as argument to the toParseY function, but when I try it I get this error (the compiler doesn't even get the

```
# command-line-arguments
./ude.go:8:2: too many arguments to return
        have ([]int)
        want ()
./ude.go:11:19: undefined: y
./ude.go:12:20: undefined: y
```

What's the proper way to achieve it in Go?

Comment: I think the code you provided isn't complete yet. Could you please provide the whole code & error?

Comment: of course, just please give me a moment to edit my question

Comment: Pleas take the Tour of Go which explains basic syntax. You got the order of argument name and type wrong in toParseY, the type is not a slice and you try to return from main instead calling into toParseY.

Comment: As @Volker suggested, you should read https://tour.golang.org/ because this is programming basics. No offense given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected code...

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    y := []int{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8}
    toParseY(y)
}

func toParseY(y []int) {
    for i, v := range y {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
    }
}
```

Issues:

1. Don't return y from main. Instead, call toParseY() from main.
2. You needed to fix the data type that toParseY accepts to be a slice of int and correct the order in which you declare the parameter. It should be parameter name, followed by data type: `toParseY(y []int)`

Output:

[image: output]